# AngularJS, how to manipulate an image obtained via $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I'm realizing a small app that get an image from server through $resource get action. The purpouse is to manipulate the obtained images and visualize them in the view.

The response from server is a series of character, which I suppose are the image itself. The response header is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.15
Date: Sat, 07 Feb 2015 15:23:39 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

So:

1. How can I use this character series in order to get something usable?
2. Once this is done, which js library I can utilize to edit this image?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449445/how-can-i-set-image-source-with-base64) to see how to set the source of an image element with a base 64 string.

A better idea is probably to use the data to [load an image into a canvas element](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/).  From there you can use any number of libraries to manipulate the image.  Perhaps something like [this](http://fabricjs.com) (I don't have any experience with Fabric, it just looked like a good example).

Comment: thx. my base64 image contains a lot of '�' character. How can I manage them?

Comment: @Nemus  Hm, base 64 should only contain printable characters.  It doesn't sound as though your string is really base 64.

Comment: Also, why bother with Angular?  If you look at the canvas tutorial I linked to above you can create a canvas element and directly load the image data from a URL.

Comment: Didactic purpose: I want to learn how to get an image via Angularjs services. Why I can get an image through web browser but not through services? How server response to my image request?