# Jquery get Request Uri too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a project which is built on ASP.NET MVC. There is a database table to store user's details including image, an api to output his details and view where i consume the api by ajax call. My api is returning the base64 value of image perfectly, but a 404 error comes saying request uri too long when i try to display the image.

Relevant lines of code are

```
$.ajax({
url: // url of api,
type: "GET",
success: function (data) {
var preview = document.querySelector('img');
preview.src = data.Image;
}
})
```

Comment: Is `data.Image` string with valid `data:image` prefix?

Comment: I have tried to browse to the api. Its giving valid base 64 image

Comment: @RachitGupta Yes, but as A. Wolff stated, the `src` attribute of `<img>` have to be correct. You can't just put a base 64 string there without correct prefix.

Comment: But that's not answering my question. How looks `data.Image`???

Comment: @A.Wolff No it wasn't. Now i have prefixed it. There is no error, but still image doesn't come in preview

Comment: Maybe you are using wrong prefix.

Comment: @A.Wolff Mattais's answer has helped me, but if i am not sure whether the image is png or jpg etc, is there a generic way to do that??

Comment: Not really AFAIK (a workaround could be easy to used but...). But you should store in database only one type of extension image, or add a field storing this info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your base64-string start with `data:image/png;base64,`?
[Look here for complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449445/how-can-i-set-image-source-with-base64).

Comment: Thanks mattias. The image does load in preview now, but what if i am not sure whether the format is png or jpg etc?

Comment: I suggest you make sure server-side and include the entire string in the response. Better yet, return a url to an action that returns the image in binary form (http://example.com/images/index/52212) and update the source with that.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Can you help me in another issue. I am trying to save the image base64 in local storage( which i believe is upto 5 MB), but i am getting exception even when the image is greater than 3.8 MB. Also i haven't stored anything else in that till now.

Comment: Sorry, don't know, but think there are still inconsistencies between browsers. Again, if you return a url to the image instead you can return it with normal cache headers so it gets cached by the browser without size restraints.

Comment: If i return a url to the image, how can it be displayed on the webpage?

Comment: Just put the url in src property of an img tag