# How to convert xml base64 string into image on the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

Managed to pull the base64 string out of the XML file with js a function but how do i display it in the browser/src attribute??  Or is there a better way!

The xml file will change so the xml photo tag image string will change. It works if i paste the text string in but need the function to update the string... if that makes sense.

```
<p id="demo">
     <script>
       var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               myFunction(this);
           }
       };
       xhttp.open("GET", "PhotoAsXML.xml", true);
       xhttp.send();

       function myFunction(xml) {
           var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
           xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FullName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>" +
           xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Photo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
         }

       </script>

  </p>

  <img style='display:block; width:140px;height:180px;' id='base64image' src="data:image/png;base64," />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set Image source with base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449445/how-can-i-set-image-source-with-base64)