# I'm trying to display an image from my database, but the image wont populate the src of the img html attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an image saved to a database by converting to a byte array to a string then i am trying to remake the image on the view. But I wanted to make it for if the image was null(no image upload) that they will get a default "no image" image. But it seems when i try to make an if statement within my view with razor. The img src is not able to find the var in the if statement. The reason i need it to fill the src on the img outside of the if statement is because when i submit the form i need it to send the img data back to the action in the controller to reconvert it and save it on the database.

I trying a view different ways to fix it, the best i can do it make scripts inside my if statement. but it still will not connect to my img src.

```
    <!--Remaking the image from a stromg to a char
    array to a byte array to a imagefrom the
    database to the original image-->
    @if (Model.ImagePath != null)
    {

        char[] imageChars = Model.ImagePath.ToCharArray();
        byte[] imageBytes = imageChars.Select(b => (byte)b).ToArray();
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
        <script>
            var img = getElementById("ImagePath").src;
            img.src = "@imgSrc";
        </script>
    }
    else
    {
        <script>
            var img = getElementById("ImagePath");
            img.src = "~/Content/no-image-icon.jpg";
            getElementById("ImagePath").width = "100";
            getElementById("ImagePath").height = "100";
        </script>
    }
    <img id="ImagePath" alt=""/>
```

when i inspect the page the script has the image converted back into the right format it just wont send it to the img src.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set Image source with base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449445/how-can-i-set-image-source-with-base64)

Comment: @Michael this does not work for me when i replace var img = getElementById("ImagePath").src;
            img.src = "@imgSrc"; with var img = getElementById("ImagePath").setAttribute('src', @imgSrc)

Comment: Doing `imageElement.src = "BASE_64"` should work, because it has a setter implemented. I recommend you trying to debug if the image format is correct. **Also your image element should be before the script tag.**

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```html
<script>
    var img = getElementById("ImagePath").src;
    img.src = "@imgSrc";
</script>
```

That looks like it is setting img.src.src, which doesn't make sense. That should probably be this, correct? :

```html
<script>
    var img = getElementById("ImagePath");
    img.src = "@imgSrc";
</script>
```

And you could also make sure to remove all line breaks:

```html
<script>
    var img = getElementById("ImagePath");
    var imgSrc = "@imgSrc";
    img.src = imgSrc.replace(/[\r|\n]/gm,'');
</script>
```

---

Also, as noted by Divya, your image element should come before your script tags, otherwise when you have `getElementById("ImagePath");`, it won't be able to find that element, since it has not loaded yet.

Comment: Also the `img` tag should be before the `script` tag for this to work properly.

Comment: I did what you guys said but still does not work, when i inspect the page it has the right values in the script but it does not populate the img tag with it still.

Comment: I figured it out i made a new vareriable in my model and added the string to it in my action that loads the page then just set that as the img src. Thank you for the help tho!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out i made a new vareriable in my model and added the string to it in my action that loads the page then just set that as the img src. Thank you for the help tho!