# Display QRCode in HTML (google authenticator)

Tags: javascript, html

I made a POST request to get a QRCode
Here is the data I get from the response. The preview of the response works fine only I don't know how to use this data to display it in a  tag on my html page for example. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449445/how-can-i-set-image-source-with-base64

Comment: `data` is base64?

Comment: @ErfanYeganegi @(Alireza Ahmadi) no I don't think it's a base64 data, and I already tried to put the data in the src of an <img>

Comment: @Rob You can't see the whole data of the response, furthermore the QrCode is cut
**BUT THANK YOU for looking after my safety, I appreciate**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It finally works as** : (in async function)

```
 const response = await fetch(URL_FOR_QRCODE, //your own url
  {
    method: "POST", //because my endpoint is a post method
    credentials: 'include' //because I use cookies (its a auth qr code)
  });

  this.QRCodeSRC = URL.createObjectURL(await response.blob());
```